# While loop will not display results when user enters "Q"

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, exit-code

I am getting this as an error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at exercises.GPACalculator.main(GPACalculator.java:53)

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
            String input = "";
    String letterGrade = "";
    String creditHour = "";
    int credits = 0;
    int points = 0;
    int course = 1;
    int gpa;
    String grade = "";

    String greeting = "Hello, this program will calculate your GPA. You will be asked \n"+
            "to enter your letter grade for each class, then you will be asked to enter \n"+
            "the corresponding number of credits for that class. Once all the grades and \n"+
            "credits have been entered, the program will display your GPA.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,greeting,"Greeting - Introduction",1);

    String gradePrompt = "Enter your letter grade (A, B, C, D, F)\n"+
            "Press \"Q\" to quit and display your results";
    String creditPrompt = "Enter the credit hours for course "+course+" (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)\n\n"+
            "Press \"Q\" to quit and display your results";

    do      
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,gradePrompt,"Enter grade",1);
        letterGrade += input.toUpperCase();

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,creditPrompt,"Enter credit hours",1);
        creditHour += input.toUpperCase();
        course++;
        if(input.toUpperCase().equals("Q"))
            continue;
            credits = Integer.parseInt(input);

            switch (grade) {
            case "A":  points = 4;
                break;
            case "B":  points = 3;
                break;
            case "C":  points = 2;
                break;
            case "D":  points = 1;
                break;
            case "F":  points = 0;
                break;
            }

        //input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Do you want to quit? (Press Q "+
        //      "to quit, no to continue)" ,"Do you want to quit?",1);
    }while(!input.toUpperCase().equals("Q"));

    input = input.substring(0,input.length()-1);

    gpa = points / credits;

    String results = "The courses you entered are:\n\n"+
            "Grade  "+"Hours    \n\n"+
            letterGrade+"   \n\n"+creditHour+"\n\n"+
            "Resulting in a GPA of "+gpa+"\n\n"+
            "This program will now terminate!";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(results),
            "GPA results",1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the stacktrace shows it is not able to convert a string to integer here :

```
credits = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Your while loop checks if input has value 'Q'. But the problem is that you update the value of input inside the while code itself. So when you provide value Q the loop will complete the current iteration and break while checking for the next iteration. I suggest you to put another input at the end of the loop.

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Do you want to quit? Press Q" ,"Do you want to quit? Press Q ",1);
```

Comment: Now I get the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at exercises.GPACalculator.main(GPACalculator.java:75)

Comment: Yes.. should be at this line - input.substring(0,input.length()-2);.. This line looks faulty. You didn't get it earlier as the execution wasn't reaching this line

Comment: Thank you that worked, but why isn't it displaying each grade/credit hour in the results? It just displays "Q" and "3".

Comment: Because you have only one variable to store grade/credit which you are printing at the end. In each iteration these variables are modified and the final value is the one during last iteration of loop. If you want to see all grades, change grade to a an int array or an ArrayList of int. Same with credits.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in this part

```
String creditPrompt = "Enter the credit hours for your course (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)\n"+
            "Enter Q to display your results\n\n";    
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,creditPrompt,"Enter grade",1);
credits = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

You are trying to parse "Q" to int. You should first check that input is not "Q" and then parse the input to get the credits

Answer (score 0):

At

```
credits = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

You are converting the input to an integer.  If the input is "Q" which is not a number, NumberFormatException will be thrown.  Either you need to give your input with a number or handle NumberFormatException in your code.